# Date type parameter in conditional query

Tags: sql, oracle, jasper-reports

I'm a newbie to *JasperReports* (I'm using *iReport 5.5.0*). I am trying to write the conditional query into the report.

I had created the following parameters:

```
$P{queryControl} <String>
${date} <Date>
${deptName} <String>
```

The parameter called $P {queryControl}, the prompt is turned off as I am setting the value at runtime checking the value of the $P{sex}.
Also, the ${date}, ${deptName} turn on the prompt.

Set the default value of the parameter as:

```
 $P{sex}.equals("F")
    ? "Select * from employees e, department d where e.staff_no = d.staff_no and      department_name = '"+${deptName}+"' and join_date >= ${date}"
    : "Select * from employees e, department d where e.staff_no = d.staff_no and department_name = '"+${deptName}+"' and join_date <= ${date}"
```

However, I found that it's not work when I run the report. And got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character found where a digit was expected.
```

When I not use ${date} in where-clause, the report can be opened.

Any solution?

Comment: What is `${date}` and `${deptName}`?

Comment: For the above SQL statement, I will input ${date} = '02/02/2013' and ${deptName} = 'Accounting'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the var ${date} (according to it's content) to a real-oracle-date. This is can be done with:

```
 $P{sex}.equals("F")
? "Select * from employees e, department d where e.staff_no = d.staff_no and      department_name = '"+${deptName}+"' and join_date >= to_date('${date}','[FORMAT]')"
: "Select * from employees e, department d where e.staff_no = d.staff_no and department_name = '"+${deptName}+"' and join_date <= to_date('${date}','[FORMAT]')"
```

instead of "[FORMAT]" insert the right Format-String there. For example:
If ${date} consist of an iso-date, like 2014-02-19, the right Format-String is 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
A Liste of all Formats could be found here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php (Scroll down)

Comment: Hello @int2000, thanks for your answering. I used the to_date('${date}', 'DD/MM/YYYY') for convert the var ${var}, however, the error is still showing. The database is using "DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS" format.

Comment: The Database isn't using any "Date-Format". It is only storing its internal DB-Format. You have to tell the DB, what ist your format (f.ex. with to_date). Please Dump the ${var}. I don't know what's in it, and what some other Software-Logic is doing with it in between of "input" and processing in the SQL